# Algorithm in IEEE format

Tags: algorithms, ieeetran, algorithmic

I want to type an algorithm in ieee format. I have used algorithmic package. But using that package, I couldn't type a caption to the algorithm and "Algorithm " above the written algorithm. What should I do to get those things written in my algorithm ? I need the algorithm as in the given figure.[image]

The structure I have used is given below

```
 \documentclass{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \begin{document}
 %\begin{algorithm}
 %\caption{Algorithm for ...}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
 \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
 \REQUIRE in
 \ENSURE  out
 \\ \textit{Initialisation} :
  \STATE first statement
 \\ \textit{LOOP Process}
  \FOR {$i = l-2$ to $0$}
  \STATE statements..
  \IF {($i \ne 0$)}
  \STATE statement..
  \ENDIF
  \ENDFOR
 \RETURN $P$ 
 \end{algorithmic} 
 %\end{algorithm}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: @vijita: `\caption` does not work outside of a floating environment ... `algoritmic` seems to be is a non-floating environment, but perhaps, there are package options to 'cure' this

Comment: @ChristianHupfer IEEE format is not compatible with the floating environment. Yes the \caption{} is not working \begin{algorithm} also. But I need that. That is why I have commented those things. Which package I have to use? can you please suggest any.

Comment: @vijita: I found the error, but Herbert was quicker in posting the same solution, see his answer and consider to accept it please, since it works ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, if you want to use the `algorithm` environment and also want to respect the IEEE format (which doesn't allow it to float), you can use the `H` floating specifier to tell `algorithm` not to float:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
```

Then, it seems that you want to use the `ruled` style for the `algorithm` environment, but without lines.

This can be achieved defining a new floating style (the `algorithm` package loads the `float` package), let's say `norules`, which has no rules

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@norules{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{}%
  \def\@fs@post{}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern3pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
\makeatother
```

and applying it to the `algorithm` environment

```
\floatstyle{norules}
\restylefloat{algorithm}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@norules{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{}%
  \def\@fs@post{}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern3pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
\makeatother
\floatstyle{norules}
\restylefloat{algorithm}

\begin{document}

 \begin{algorithm}[H]
 \caption{Algorithm for ...}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
 \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
 \REQUIRE in
 \ENSURE  out
 \\ \textit{Initialisation} :
  \STATE first statement
 \\ \textit{LOOP Process}
  \FOR {$i = l-2$ to $0$}
  \STATE statements..
  \IF {($i \ne 0$)}
  \STATE statement..
  \ENDIF
  \ENDFOR
 \RETURN $P$
 \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: for helping me. :)

Comment: @vijita You're welcome. Anyway it seems that Herbert's answer was what you were lookin for ;-)

Comment: :-) I was lookin for algorithm in IEEE format. I think herbert's ans also gives algorithm in IEEE format and I 've made it as ans before ur post.

Comment: @vijita Happy you've solved, anyway.

Comment: :) me too.. of course with the help of u people... :)

Answer (score 13):

Load also `algorithm`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm}
 \caption{Algorithm for ...}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
 \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
 \REQUIRE in
 \ENSURE  out
 \\ \textit{Initialisation} :
  \STATE first statement
 \\ \textit{LOOP Process}
  \FOR {$i = l-2$ to $0$}
  \STATE statements..
  \IF {($i \ne 0$)}
  \STATE statement..
  \ENDIF
  \ENDFOR
 \RETURN $P$ 
 \end{algorithmic} 
 \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Herbert . Can I remove that lines in between?

Comment: After loading package `algorithm` write `\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{algorithm}`

Comment: By default the IEEEtran centers a caption if it is shorter than a line